# google app script documentation clear formatting api

Tags: google-apps-script

I would like to write a google app script to automatically clear the default text formatting of my uploaded/converted google text documents.  When editing a google document in google drive, this can be done manually by selecting the text and clicking the the "Format\Clear formatting" drop-down menu item.

I am wondering if there exists such google app api or apis or any other suggestions for doing this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps Script **can't run on document upload**. So you can't do this without having to install script on every document. And it takes longer than just pressing <kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd> and clicking the clear formatting button.

Comment: My request is not to run google app script while uploading documents but afterward.  

If I have lots of documents in a folder, I can write a google app script to open all the documents and start batch process them automatically without going through the labor to open, change format one by one. 

I have written app script to automate simple things like changing paragraph styles (using setHeading) for selected keywords, etc. So, I am looking for api to automate the clear formatting fuctionality.